# Pre-processor macros in xcconfig files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, xcconfig

is is possible to use macros in config files? I want to achieve something like:

```
if iPad
set variable to 1
else
set variable to 0
```

Is that possible? I would rather not use scripts for this.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/13541297/5790492

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You generally should check this at runtime rather than compile time. See [iOS - conditional compilation (xcode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581700/ios-conditional-compilation-xcode).

If you don't do it that way, I typically recommend using different targets as hinted at by @Robert Vojta.

That said, I can imagine cases where this would be useful in some piece of shared code. So...

There is an xcconfig variable you can use called `TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY`. It returns 1 for iPhone and iPod Touch, and 2 for iPad. This can be used to create a kind of macro. I don't highly recommend this approach, but here's how you do it. Let's say you were trying to set some value called `SETTINGS`:

```
// Family 1 is iPhone/iPod Touch. Family 2 is iPad
SettingsForFamily1 = ...
SettingsForFamily2 = ...
SETTINGS = $(SettingsForFamily$(TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY))
```

I've done this a few times in my projects (for other problems, not for iPad detection). Every time I've done it, a little more thought has allowed me to remove it and do it a simpler way (usually finding another way to structure my project to remove the need). But this is a technique for creating conditionals in xcconfig.

Comment: That's a great tip! Thanks, but what do you do if the TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY flag is universal, i.e. returns 1,2?

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK it's not possible. But if you want to solve simple task - lot of common settings and just few variables have different values, you can do this:

**generic.xcconfig:**

```
settings for both configs
```

**ipad.xcconfig:**

```
#include "generic.xcconfig"
ipad-specific-settings
```

**iphone.xcconfig**

```
#include "generic.xcconfig"
iphone-specific-settings
```

This can solve your condition need. I do use this schema frequently.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. Configuration files are not preprocessed (and compiled). What are you trying to do?